# Best free alternative for Quizlet

Tags: gratis, android, web-apps, learning

Unfortunately, Quizlet has paywalled its most basic learning functionality, so now I'm looking for a free alternative.

The functionality I'm looking for is the following: you define a set of terms, along with their definition (a set in Quizlet), then the definitions are shown to you one by one, and you have to answer each term correctly by typing it in full. In the first round, each definition is shown, then in the second one, only the ones whose term you failed to answer correctly in the first round. This goes on until you manage to type all of the terms correctly.

Can you recommend me any other app (for Android or for the web) that has the same functionality, but for free? So far, I've tried AnkiDroid, but it doesn't support answering by typing the term in full.

Comment: That's basically the "Flashcard principle". I'm not using any of those so I cannot tell which of them might support requiring fully typed answers, but you can find a collection of such apps in my listing of [Vocabulary & Flash Cards](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/school_flashcards). Should you identify one that fits your needs, be welcome to [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search, I managed to find the perfect alternative, [knowt.io](https://knowt.io/). This website has the same functionality as Quizlet, and what I was looking for. It also supports importing sets from Quizlet, and I've already moved several of my previous sets there. The only downside is that it doesn't have an app version, so the experience is not perfect on mobile yet.

Answer (score 0):

There are some flashcard android apps (FOSS) on [F-Droid](https://search.f-droid.org/?q=flash%20card&lang=en).
Such as:

- Flash Deck (GPLv3) [link](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/m.co.rh.id.a_flash_deck/)
- FlashCards (MIT) [link](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.quchen.flashcard/)
- Mobile Pauker ++ (GPLv3) [link](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.daniel.mobilepauker2/)
- Mnemododo (GPLv2) [link](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.tbrk.mnemododo/), [website](https://www.tbrk.org/software/mnemododo.html)
- AnyMemo (GPLv2) [link](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.liberty.android.fantastischmemo/), [website](https://anymemo.org/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you read my whole question, you must notice that I'm NOT looking for a flashcard-based alternative. Actually, I need an app that enables me to do the same typing- and round-based learning method Quizlet has. Does any of these apps have such a functionality?

Comment: That is 5 different answers.  Please post them separately so that they may be voted upon and accepted separately.  Also, as others have commented, please exlain *why* these are suitable apps.

Answer (score 0):

I created a site for my daughter and then I made it public. You can maybe give a try to [www.vocaquiz.com](https://www.vocaquiz.com) which is free. You can create a set of terms and study them. I will add more feature if it is get used :)

Comment: Does it support the functionality I describe in my question? I'm specifically looking for that, there are so many general flashcards apps and websites out there, but what I'm looking for is not supported by most of them.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly! One [Quizlet Alternative](https://www.hoffnmazor.com/blog/top-quizlet-alternatives/) that offers similar functionality for free is "StudyBlue." StudyBlue allows you to create flashcards with terms and definitions, and it provides a learning mode where you can test yourself on these flashcards by typing in the full term. It also adapts the learning process based on your responses, similar to what you described. StudyBlue is available for both Android and web platforms, so you can access it from anywhere. Give it a try, and hopefully, it will meet your learning needs!

Comment: This service is not operational anymore.